# How can I compare specific ranges of data between two excel worksheets, identify the differences, and fill in the blanks?

Tags: vba, excel

I cannot seem to solve this VBA riddle I've been working on, please help. I'm new at this and I'm probably over complicating it

Essentially, there are two worksheets - one titled *Master* and the other will be created fresh daily by date. The *Master tab* contains 10000 rows of historical data filled from *Columns A:X*. The other tab generally has about 300 rows of fresh data and also contains like *Columns A:X*, only with blank cells in *Columns A:B*. I'm trying to find matches with the master tab, and if so, populate the corresponding results in cells A and B from the master to the daily. If nothing, leave blank. It is crucial that *Cells H:M* and *R:W* are identical matches.

Below is my crazy attempt, Thank you in advance for helping

```
Sub Previous()

Dim u As Long
u = 2
Do While ActiveSheet.Cells(u, 6) <> ""
    Dim i As Long
    i = 2
    Do While Worksheets("Master").Cells(i, 6) <> ""
        If ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(u, 8), Cells(u, 13)) _
            = Worksheets("Master").Range(Cells(i, 8), Cells(i, 13)) _
            And ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(u, 18), Cells(u, 23)) _
            = Worksheets("Master").Range(Cells(i, 18), Cells(i, 23)) _
            And ActiveSheet.Cells(u, 2) = "" Then
                ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(u, 1), Cells(u, 2)) _
                = Worksheets("Master").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2))
        Else: i = i + 1
        End If   
    Loop
    u = u + 1
    i = 2
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: So what results are you getting with your attempt? Are you recieving an error? What exactly is going *wrong*?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this ckuhn203. I'm getting a debug error for run time (application-defined or object-defined) in the If statement. Ideally I would like cells A & B to copy/paste or transfer from the master tab to the matching rows on the date tab

Comment: Break it down and simplify the problem. Focus on the if line then. I'm sorry. I don't have time to debug your code right now. Update your question with the info you commented to me. Indicate *in your question* what *exact* error message you're receiving and what *exact* line is throwing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub Previous()

Dim actWs As Worksheet

Set actWs = ActiveSheet

Dim mstWs As Worksheet

Set mstWs = Sheets("Master")

Dim u As Long

Dim i As Long

u = 2

Do While actWs.Cells(u, 6) <> ""

For i = 2 To mstWs.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

```
If actWs.Cells(u, 8) = mstWs.Cells(i, 8) And actWs.Cells(u, 9) = mstWs.Cells(i, 9) And actWs.Cells(u, 10) = mstWs.Cells(i, 10) And actWs.Cells(u, 11) = mstWs.Cells(i, 11) And actWs.Cells(u, 12) = mstWs.Cells(i, 12) And actWs.Cells(u, 13) = mstWs.Cells(i, 13) And actWs.Cells(u, 18) = mstWs.Cells(i, 18) And actWs.Cells(u, 19) = mstWs.Cells(i, 19) And actWs.Cells(u, 20) = mstWs.Cells(i, 20) And actWs.Cells(u, 21) = mstWs.Cells(i, 21) And actWs.Cells(u, 22) = mstWs.Cells(i, 22) And actWs.Cells(u, 23) = mstWs.Cells(i, 23) Then
mstWs.Select
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2)).Select
Selection.Copy
actWs.Select
Range(Cells(u, 1), Cells(u, 2)).Select
actWs.Paste
End If

Next i
```

u = u + 1

Loop

End Sub

Comment: I did it! Finally came up with some workable code with verified testing. I'm sure there is probably a better way to compare the ranges, but long hand seems to work just fine

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't believe this snippet does what you think it does.

```
Worksheets("Master").Range(Cells(i, 8), Cells(i, 13))
```

In that snippet `Cells(i,8)` references the `ActiveSheet`, not `Sheets("Master")`.
There is a note on this about [halfway down the page on msdn's Range Object documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

You can simplify your code a great deal by assigning some worksheet variables.

```
dim actWs as Worksheet
dim mstWs as Worksheet
Set actWs = Activesheet
Set mstWs = Sheets("Master")
'then reference your ranges like this
mstWs.Cells(i,8)
```

But, that's not what is causing your runtime error.

Simply put, you can not compare ranges that way. You need to check the value of each cell, so you end up with another layer of nested loops.

```
dim u as long ' active sheet row counter
dim i as long ' master sheet row counter
dim c as long ' column counter

For u = 2 to actWs.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'find last row in column "A" of active sheet
    For i = 2 to  mstWs.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'find last row in column "A" of master sheet
        For c = 8 to 13
            If actWs.Cells(i,c) = mstWs.Cells(i,c) Then
                'Do stuff
            End if
        next c 'next column
    next i 'next master sheet row
next u 'next active sheet row
```

This is obviously a simplified version of what you'll need to do. Be careful of line continuations (" _ ") and code indentation. It's easy to trick yourself into thinking your program should flow in a way that it isn't. It would be advisable to store the value's you're checking for equality in variables to make it easier to read. You might more readily notice where you're going wrong.

Comment: This is solid advice, Thank you! I'll tinker with it over the next few days. I appreciate you taking the time to point me in the right direction

Comment: You're welcome @user3672976. I'm sorry I didn't have the patience to work out a full solution. Please come back and post your own answer when you've worked it out.